# Looping through multiple array of objects looking for items that match multiple arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I am creating a survey which has questions with different weightings.

Each variable below resembles a category filled with the corresponding question ids

I want to make a calculation per category which will be the score of each corresponding question id in each array.

```
// Category arrays 
let $A = ['1', '3', '8'];
let $B = ['2', '4'];
let $C = ['5', '6', '7'];

for (var j = 0; j < app.length; j++) {
    var subArr = app[j]['questions'];
}
```

like so

```
subArr prints out 4 separate array of objects
```

like so

```
[{id:1, score: 4}, {id:2, score: 4}, {id:3, score: 3}]
[{id:4, score: 3}, {id:5, score: 2}, {id:6, score: 1}]
[{id:7 , score: 3}, {id:8, score: 3}]
```

So in pseudo code terms, I want to loop through the subArr, and find every objects that matches the ids in each category array. I then want to save the score of each of these matched items in a separate array, and then calculate the average

so I would end up with the average score of each category

I've got this so far

like so

```
for (var j = 0; j < app.length; j++) {
    var subArr = app[j]['questions'];
    console.log('questions', subArr)

        arrOfArr.forEach(function(dataId) {
            console.log(dataId)
                    const $findMatchingId = subArr.find((item)=>item.id == dataId);
                                          
        })
}
```

like so

```
when i console.log($findMatchingId) it returns undefined ?
```

Comment: What's app defined as?

I'm also not really clear on what the relationship is between the three sets of arrays you mention.

Comment: All your data looks very disconnected and thus difficult to work with. Should be able to structure this so you keep track of answers in a more structured object associated to questions

Comment: Like, take [{id:1, score: 4}, {id:2, score: 4}, {id:3, score: 3}]. Is that scored, averaged categories or is it individual questions.

Given an array of scores, what's wrong with either example.reduce( (sum,current)=>sum+current),0) / example.length?

that could even be example.map(object_element=>object_element.score).reduce()...